# Unable to locate inline CSS causing parts of page to be blank

Tags: plugins, css, widgets

Large parts on [a live Wordpress page](https://seattlemakers.org/memberships/) shows blank because a piece of inline CSS has `opacity` set to `0`. Unfortunately I am unable to find where this inline CSS lives.

```
<div class="grve-element grve-text vc_custom_1655582827387">
    <div class="ptsTableFrontedShell">
    <!-- Style to display all tables correct-->
    <!-- this block will be remove in frontend.tables.editor.block.base after init -->
    <div class="ptsPreDisplayStyle">
        <style>
            .ptsBlock {
                opacity: 0;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
        </style>
```

`vc_custom` refers to Visual Composer which apparently now is WPBakery. Given that information I looked into the Row, Column and Text Block settings when editing the page with WPBakery but couldn't find any custom CSS.

Regarding ID 1655582827387, I have no clue where to start searching for this ID. Lastly, it's unclear to me where the class `ptsBlock` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Finding inline CSS can be a right pain.

In your case, the problem is `visibility: hidden;` which means nothing is going to show up. You could add your own custom CSS and override it with the `!important` rule.

So, for example, you could put this somewhere in the header. Most themes have a custom CSS section in the customize menu - that might be best.

```
 .ptsBlock {
      opacity: 1 !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
 }
```

This works by raising the priority of your CSS over the CSS that does not have the rule.